# How to select the drop down values in selenium from hidden select

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, getelementbyid

I am pretty new to java selenium and I am trying to select drop down values from the attached drop down, but the thing is that this drop down is customized and broken into 3 parts( anchor, the icon and the select with drop down values under a div).

How can I locate and get these values.

[image]

Comment: show what you've tried already and exceptions you get with your code

Comment: I tried going from main div to ul and then to the drop down values.

Comment: DriverManager.getWebDriver().findElement(By.id("select2-drop"));
  Assert.assertTrue(true);
  
  DriverManager.getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='select2-results-50']"));
  Assert.assertTrue(true);
  
  DriverManager.getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='select2-results-50']/li[1]"));
  Assert.assertTrue(true);
  
  DriverManager.getWebDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("#select2-result-label-54"));
  Assert.assertTrue(true); in this case its not able to find the element only

Comment: I also used the select statement but in that case i got an error saying that element should be select but its span

Comment: Select select = new Select (DriverManager.getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='page-content']/form/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/select")));
  select.selectByVisibleText("Alias");
  Assert.assertTrue(true);

Comment: Try this one `Select select = new Select (DriverManager.getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='s2id_autogen50']/following-sibling::select"))); select.selectByVisibleText("Alias");` Same result?

Comment: well i dont know if this worked because i am getting another error now,org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'

Comment: it did not work, infact I tried using

  Actions action = new Actions(DriverManager.getWebDriver());
  action.clickAndHold(objIngestPage.SystemOfOrigin().getWebElement()).perform();
  objassetSearchPage.pause(100);
  action.release().perform(); and this gives an error saying buttondown did not match the known command

Comment: `Actions` cannot be used (for now) with `Firefox`. You can try `Chrome` instead

Comment: I solved the issue. Thanks